# Add common commands to WSL autocomplete suggestions

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal, sequelize.js, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been learning about the JavaScript library Sequelize and have noticed some boilerplate code for the sequelize-CLI. For example to generate a model you often use something like this:

`npx sequelize-cli model:generate --name SingularModelNameHere --attributes attribute1Name:datatype, attribute2Name:dataType`

My question is how do I go about adding these sorts of "boilerplates" to my Ubuntu so that I can easily use the tab-autocomplete feature and replace the boilerplate with the appropriate code? I've seen [this tutorial](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/add-bash-auto-completion-in-ubuntu-linux/), however they use the `host` command by itself and `google.com`, `cyberciti.biz`, and `nixcraft.com` are separate autocomplete arguments.

Is there a way to make it so that I could type `npx sequelize-cli`  in my terminal and use tab to autocomplete the `model:generate --name SingularModelNameHere --attributes attribute1Name:datatype, attribute2Name:dataType` boilerplate?

I'd like to add other boilerplate commands too. For example,

`npx sequelize-cli seed:generate --name <descriptiveName>`

Then if I typed `npx sequelize-cli s` I could tab autocomplete.

Comment: Hi! Tab completion is really meant for completing things one option/argument at a time, which doesn't really match your use case. Can I suggest an alternative? Every command you type in bash in Linux can get saved to a "history" file. If you set that up, and make the history file size large (so *everything* gets saved), you can then use Ctrl-r to quickly search through it. For example `Ctrl+r model:generate` should find the last `npx ... model:generate ...` command and then you can hit Enter to run it. https://superuser.com/questions/7414/how-can-i-search-the-bash-history-and-rerun-a-command.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to go about this, but first, it's important to understand that "completion" is a feature of your Linux *shell* not of WSL.  If you haven't changed it, `bash` is most likely your shell, as it is the default in most distributions.  Some common alternatives include `zsh` and `fish`.

While I generally don't "advertise" for my favorite shell in answers, I think it's appropriate in this case since one of the big features in the [fish shell](https://fishshell.com) is its great out-of-the-box completion, suggestion, and abbreviation system.

As omajid mentioned in the comments, most shells can accomplish what you want to some degree through history search.  But regardless of what shell you choose, I'd recommend adding [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) and setting up its shell integration.  It can turbo-charge that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> history search with an extremely fast pattern search.

You can type `npx seq`, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, and then filter based on flags that you'd used before. `npx seed` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> would show all your commands with `npx` and `seed`, regardless of where they appear in the commandline.

Even something as simple as `seqseed` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> would find those lines.

That could handle your "multiple boilerplate" scenario.  Again, this can be set up to work in Bash, Zsh, or fish.

But fish also has an out-of-the-box [Autosuggestions](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#autosuggestions) feature that can help with this.  As you type each command, fish will "suggest" a previously typed commandline that you can accept with <kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.  Or you can just accept one argument at a time from that previous commandline with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>.

Finally, fish has built-in [Abbreviation](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/abbr.html) support that could be used for this workflow:

```
abbr --add seqgen npx sequelize-cli model:generate --name SingularModelNameHere --attributes attribute1Name:datatype, attribute2Name:dataType
abbr --add seqseed npx sequelize-cli seed:generate --name
```

Then, typing `seqseed` followed by the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> will replace the `seqseed` with `npx sequelize-cli seed:generate --name`, leaving the cursor at the end where you can add the `<descriptiveName>`.

A few other commandline editing tips for this type of work.  Some of these are found in other shells:

| Key | Function |
| --- | --- |
| <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> | Deletes previous token. Fish is smart enough to use things like `/` and `:` as token separators by default, so if you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> after `attribute2Name:dataType`, it will *only* remove `dataType`. |
| <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> | Skip backward and forward over tokens |
| <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> | Edit the current commandline in your preferred `$EDITOR`. |